# $_GET parametters not working in an specific template

Tags: posts, themes, pages, url-rewriting

i'm developing a plugin wich uses GET parametters to decide what to render to the user(example: login, logout, change password etc..), the thing is this works in the standards wordpress themes but when i changed to my clients theme(Sereno) every time i call the url with the parametter it render a POST page... example

if a call
http://localhost/myclient/?page_id=822&action=passresset
in the standard wp theme it will show what i want but if a change to sereno shows a post page, its weird to my that does not show an 404 error, like this recognizes the URL like a valid one

I'm trying to fix this but i have no idea where to start, i guess the problem should be in the way the template decides what kind of loop it will use but i don't know where the **** its that script..

Pleace help!!

--------------UPDATE---------------

first than all, fuxia thanks a lot for taking time on helping me...

i'm using a widget to handle a type of users (not the same users of WP) which will have access to login, logout, change password, resset password and send requests via a form so my widget class is as follows

```
class SucursalWidget extends baseWidget {

public function __construct() {
    $widgetOptions = [
        'classname' => 'SucursalWidget',
        'description' => 'Panel de búsqueda para las sucursales',
    ];

    parent::__construct('sucursalwidget', "Widget para las sucursales", $widgetOptions);
}

public function login() {
  //process user login
}

public function logout() {
    session_destroy();
    echo "<h2>Su sesion ha sido terminada</h2>";
    $model = new LoginForm();
    $this->renderPartial('loginform', ['model' => $model]);
}

public function solicitud() {
  //Gets a form an save it on db
}

/**
 * Cambiar contraseña para usuario ya logeado
 */
public function passChange() {

}

/**
 * Recuperar contraseña perdida vía email
 */
public function passResset() {
   //PROCEESS pass resset
}

public function widget($args, $instance) {
    $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : 'login';

    switch ($action) {
        case 'login': {
                $this->login();
            }
            break;
        case 'logout': {
                $this->logout();
            }
            break;
        case 'solicite': {
                $this->solicitud();
            }
            break;
        case 'passchange': {
                $this->passChange();
            }
            break;
        case 'passresset': {
                $this->passResset();
            }
            break;

        default: {
                echo "Página no encontrada";
            }
            break;
    }
}

}
```

as you can see in the function widget the switch uses the $_GET['action'] to know what to do with depending on the user's actions, this method works just fine when i use a regular WP theme like Twenty Fifteen. I guess the theme (named Sereno) its changing the URLs pattern because when i put any extra get parametter it shows a POST page i would expect an 404 error if something goes wrong, but for some reason is showing the last POST and i have no idea what to search for in the theme code..

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is removing all unknown (not registered) `$_GET` parameters while processing the request (same is true for `$_POST`).

You can either register the custom variable, or just go the canonical PHP way by using [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php). This will access the original, unchanged `GET` parameters.

If you are using `filter_input()`, you have to hook into `pre_get_posts` to change the fetched resource.

You can also filter `query_vars` and register your custom variable here. This will make sure it is preserved.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function ( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'sereno';
    return $vars;
});
```

Then you can access it per `get_query_var( 'sereno' )` now. You still have to change the request somehow if you want to show some custom content.

Comment: already tried that...the thing is my plugin is not working only with one specific template, i'll love to know where the templates decide what view file to use( i mean archive.php, single.php etc..) so i can see where the template is failling..

Comment: @IsanRodriguezTrimiño And here is the basic problem with your question: You left out the crucial part with your own code. :) Please update your question.

Comment: first than all, fuxia thanks a lot for taking time on helping me...

Answer (score 0):

I had found the problem, the thing is this template has taxonomy customizations, i commented

```
require_once('library/core/twomediax-wp-customizations.php'); // twomediax core custom types and taxonomies
```

this line is in the function.php, and without this customizations it works, now is giving me othe issues with template widget but i have a path to follow... now i have to struggle with taxonomies

fuxia thanks again for helping me